# Unable to generate a proxy for a self-hosted service with "Add Service Reference"

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I created a basic calculator service called MiniCalc that only has two operations. Add and Mul, and hosted it in a Console Application.

```
using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MiniCalcService.Service),
                                         new Uri("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MiniCalcService.IService),
                            new BasicHttpBinding(),
                            "Service");
    host.Open();
    Console.Write("Press ENTER key to terminate the MiniCalcHost . . . ");
}
```

Then I created a console application to consume the service and created the proxy manually by creating a proxy class and then created a ChannelFactory to invoke the service.

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service");
IService proxy = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(),ep);
```

**I was able to invoke the service contract properly and retrieve the result as expected.**

Now I wanted to create the proxy using the `Add Service Reference`.

I get the following error when I click Go in the Add Service Reference window

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: When You access the .svc in the browser it shows some example of how to use or something about your service not providing information about it?

Comment: There is no .svc file. I have only created a Service.cs and its corresponding IService.cs. Please don't mind my ignorance, but is .svc file a necessity, should we wish to use tools to generate the proxy and consume the service?

Comment: Ignorance is if you never asked. Nobody knows everything. In some point you need to start from zero. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Metadata exchange behavior in your ServiceHost.

```
using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MiniCalcService.Service),
                             new Uri("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MiniCalcService.IService),
                            new BasicHttpBinding(),
                            "Service");

    //Enable metadata exchange
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
    Console.Write("Press ENTER key to terminate the MiniCalcHost . . . ");
}
```

http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Self-Hosting.aspx

Comment: minmin, I have added the above lines to enable the metadata exchange, but still I get the same error when trying to Add Service Reference.

Comment: minmin, your answer worked for me. My mistake was thinking that endpoint and address are the same. So the URL: `http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service` is the endpoint and should be used in the manual proxy as described in my post originally and URL: `http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService` is the address and should be used in the Add Service Reference window.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a .svc I think you must have this in your service .config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="MiniCalcService.Service" />
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

After that you need an option to allow service metadata:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

This is a bit more complicated so I advise you tu create a new WCF Service in a new Solution then you can see how this configuration looks like. So you only need to make some copy/paste configurations.

After that point to:

http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service.svc

Comment: Vitor, is it possible to achieve the above in code instead of configuration? I ask this because I don't have the app.config file yet.

Comment: You can add an app.config easily pointing to File-> Add -> Application Configuration File. If you don't want the config I think you can achieve this with an aproach like @minmin wrote.

Comment: I have now achieved what I wanted using minmin's code. I posted an explanation under his answer. Thank you for your assistance.