# WCF EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, sharpdevelop

I am working on a simple WCF service, `MiniCalcService` which has only one operation `Add`. The client and host are both console applications. The client application takes in the operands necessary for each operation and passes them over to the service. The service returns the result which would be displayed on the client console.

- Host is running
- I am doing everything in code so far and there is no app.config.
- There is no large data being passed, just two or three numbers

This worked for me yesterday. Today when I tried the same thing, it throws the following exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService that could accept the message.

Here is the [Stack Trace](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1535497). Not that it might matter, but `MiniCalcClient` is developed in Visual Studio and `MiniCalcService` and `MiniCalcHost` are developed in SharpDevelop.

**MiniCalcHost**:

```
using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MiniCalcService.Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MiniCalcService.IService),new BasicHttpBinding(),"Service");

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Serving MiniCalcService since {0}", DateTime.Now);
    Console.Write("Press ENTER key to terminate the MiniCalcHost . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

**MiniCalcClient:**

```
static string Calculator(string operation, params string[] strOperands)
{
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService");
    IService proxy = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);

    int[] operands;
    string result = string.Empty;

    try { operands = Array.ConvertAll(strOperands, int.Parse); }
    catch (ArgumentException) { throw; }

    switch (operation)
    {
        case "add":
            result = Convert.ToString(proxy.Add(operands));//<---EXCEPTION 
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Why was this reachable again?");
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Service Contract IService**:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="learning.wcf.MiniCalc")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(params int[] operands);
}
```

Can you please help me identify what's causing this exception?

---

**Solution:** I changed this line:

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService");
```

to this:

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/Service");
```

and it worked.

Comment: Can you show us the service contract (`IService1`) ??

Comment: I added the service contract `IService`.

Comment: Yes it is decorated with ServiceContractAttribute. No reason why int shouldn't be used, but I had a `Mul` method originally and had `double` since the Operation Contracts were variadic in nature. So just used double for `Add` also to have consistency.

Comment: If you add `int` - you'll always get `int` - so for consistency reasons, you should use `int` as the return value, too. `double` really doesn't make sense. Also: if you do want to use non-int, then you should use `decimal` for higher accuracy than double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use the `params` in a WCF service call.... seems unnecessary, anyway....

Could you try these two service contracts instead, just to see if those would work:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="learning.wcf.MiniCalc")]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int op1, int op2);
}
```

and

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="learning.wcf.MiniCalc")]
public interface IService3
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Add(List<int> operands);
}
```

I'm just wondering if removing the `params` from your service contract might make it run - everything seems fine at first glance...

---

OK, so it wasn't this first attempt ......

---

Well - quite obvious, really: you're using a `using` block around the service host instantiation:

```
using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MiniCalcService.Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MiniCalcService.IService),new BasicHttpBinding(),"Service");

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Serving MiniCalcService since {0}", DateTime.Now);
    Console.Write("Press ENTER key to terminate the MiniCalcHost . . . ");
}
```

So by the time the code reaches the closing bracket `}`, the `ServiceHost` instance will be disposed and thus the service host closed. There's no running service host anymore!

You need to **stop the code execution** somewhere after the call to `host.Open()` by e.g.

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

or something else.

So your first claim that *Host is running* really doesn't hold up - it's running briefly and then is terminated again right away.....

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I really had the `Console.ReadKey(true)` and just added it to the code right now as I missed it in the first place. That is why is mentioned first that the host is running.

Comment: @KishorNanda: updated my response with two possible new service contracts - could you see if those would work??

Comment: I just added a new service IService2 and implemented it and hosted it just the same way. Then copied the proxy over to Host and changed the code accordingly to call IService2. Still I get the same EndpointNotFoundException. :(
I will try the IService3 and get back to you in a moment.

Comment: Marc_s, Even IService3 did not work. I should mention that 1) since I am on Windows 7, I opened both IDEs as Administrator from the beginning; 2) before asking the question, I opened the Project created in SharpDevelop in Visual Studio and tried, that didn't work either.

Comment: Marc_s, I asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9852019/539542) yesterday and got confused between endpoint and address. I explained under minmin's answer what my mistake was. Just to see if reversing that would work, I changed the EndpointAddress to `http://localhost:8091/MiniCalcService/ServiceN` and tried. It worked! I don't really understand that EndpointAddress had to specified like this for the service to be contacted properly. Can you throw some light on this?

Comment: After I posted the above comment, I could get ahead of my confusion and see what changed between yesterday and today. I am marking your post as answer as you helped me go through the thought process. Thanks!